# can't add an expression for a subfield in MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

Here is my code.

```
   Cart
        .aggregate()
        .match(where)
        .lookup({
            from: "product_catelogs",
            foreignField: "_id",
            localField: "product_id",
            as: "product"
        })
        .project({
          product: {
            $arrayElemAt: ["$product", 0]
          },
          "product.custom_field": {
            $add: [1, 1]
          },
          product_quantity: 1,
          product_variant: 1,
          guest_token: 1,
          user_id: 1,
          product_id: 1,
        })
```

In this I want to add a custom field with product object. but when I am trying to do so, I am facing this kind of error,

> can't add an expression for a subfield of product because there is
>   already an expression that applies to the whole field

Please help me out.

Comment: Please add the sample document for both the schemas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid the only way you could go about this is to add another project pipeline that has projections of the `product` embedded fields individually together with the new field. An example follows:

```
Cart.aggregate()
    .match(where)
    .lookup({
        "from": "product_catelogs",
        "foreignField": "_id",
        "localField": "product_id",
        "as": "product"
    })
    .project({
        "product": { "$arrayElemAt": ["$product", 0] },
        "product_quantity": 1,
        "product_variant": 1,
        "guest_token": 1,
        "user_id": 1,
        "product_id": 1,
    })
    .project({
        "product.field1": "$product.field1", // <-- change to suit your actual schema
        "product.field2": "$product.field2",
        "product.field3": "$product.field3",
        "product.field4": "$product.field4",
        "product.custom_field": { "$add": ["$product.field4", "$product.field5"] },
        "product_quantity": 1,
        "product_variant": 1,
        "guest_token": 1,
        "user_id": 1,
        "product_id": 1,
    })
```

Comment: ya... it is working. is there anyway except this.. because it is taking more lines of code. I'm just asking. But it is working well...!!! thank you very much.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't think there's any other way